# Perl Check whether file is open

Tags: perl

I am having perl 5.005_30 version.

I need to check whether a ".doc" file is already in use before performing any operation.

I have written the following code.

```
my $doc = "D:\Test.doc";
eval{open FILE, ">$doc" or die "error"};
if($@) 
{
    my $ERR_MSG ="Could not open the file \"$doc\" !\n Please close the file if it is already open and try again !!\n";

    open (LOGFILE, '>>Logfile.txt');
    print LOGFILE "$ERR_MSG\n";
}
else
{
    close(FILE); // close the opened file and start operations on ".doc" file using MS word API.
    ...
    ...
}
```

With this code, if the "Test.doc" is already open, it prints an error message in log file which is OK. However if "Test.doc" is not already open, the open method opens the .doc file and in the else condition while closing the file ["close(FILE)"] the existing contents of the "Test.doc" is removed and the document becomes empty.

Please let me how to close the file without emptying its contents.

Comment: Don't use a version of perl from last century. Upgrade to something current. 5.18.2 is stable now.

Comment: Use exclusive [locking](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) to make sure that file is not in use.

Comment: It may not be the best way to go about it, but you could try opening the DOC to append with `>>` instead of to clobber with `>`.   Also, you could just check the return value of `open` without mucking about with `eval`.  This doesn't really qualify as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was typing my answer when you made this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to overwrite it:

```
eval{open FILE, ">$doc" or die "error"};
```

You could try to open it for append:

```
eval{open FILE, ">>$doc" or die "error"};
```

Comment: Although I'm guessing the API expects to open the file itself anyway, so I'm not sure if the whole exercise makes sense.